# Symplectomorphism between square and disk of the same area

Tags: symplectic-geometry

I understand that the disk and square of area $1$ are symplectomorphic in $\mathbb{R}^2$ but I can't construct a map that preserves the standard form on $\mathbb{R}^2$. How is this done?